# Creating Cron job in OpenShift online results in: admission webhook "validate.cron.create" denied the request: Prohibited resource for this cluster

Tags: cron, kubernetes-cronjob, openshift-online

I'm learning Openshift Online, I tried to create a cron job from either UI or CLI, both resulted in the below error:

Error from server: admission webhook "validate.cron.create" denied the request: Prohibited resource for this cluster.

I checked permissions for the account, and it had admin rights with CRUD on cronjobs..

I use the same example as documentation:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"  
  jobTemplate:             
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:          
            parent: "cronjobpi"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: pi
            image: perl
            command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Unfortunately, CronJob can be available on OpenShift Online Pro. Refer [here](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html#overview). So if you use the cluster as Starter plan, you can not create CronJob.

Comment: thanks @DaeinPark,you are right, I'm using trial version.. it took me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

So as @Daein Park mentioned :
Unfortunately, CronJob can be available on OpenShift Online Pro. So if you use the cluster as Starter plan, you can not create CronJob.

https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html#overview